# What is "All shells and programs that use exec*p library calls handle searching"?

Tags: shell

I came across this sentence in the following documentation but couldn't understand it, and the link to one of its terms appeared broken to me. Can someone help?

> All shells and programs that use exec*p library calls handle searching
>   for executables in directories named in PATH

[Source](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~bsy/cse80/lab1/envar.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse it:

> All *shells* and *programs* that use **`exec*p`** library calls

next is the verb:

> ***handle*** searching for executables in directories named in **`PATH`**

The **`exec*p`** refers to a subset of the system "exec" functions, whose name ends with **p**, as a clue to the fact that they (as the rest of the sentence says) use the environment variable `PATH` as a list of directories to *search* for executable programs with a given name (a parameter of the function).

Further reading:

- [execl, execlp, execle, execv, execvp, execvpe - execute a file](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) 
  This is an example of the page that *[Shell and Environment Variables](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~bsy/cse80/lab1/envar.html)* might point to.
- [How does **`execvp`** run a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301407/how-does-execvp-run-a-command)