# Is there any difference w/ v/s w/o "./" in a relative path?

Tags: filenames, slash

Is there any subtle difference between:

```
file
```

and

```
./file
```

as a relative path?

Comment: `file` wont execute but `./file` will however I don't think that is your question.

Comment: It can be useful to include the `./` when the file you're referring to would otherwise be misunderstood as a commandline argument, such as in `rm -who-uses-filenames-like-this` vs `rm ./-who-uses-filenames-like-this`

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261190/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used as a command name in a shell or in the `exec*p()` libc functions, `file` would look-up `file` in `$PATH` (or for a shell, possibly invoke the built-in version, or function by that name), while `./file` would run the one the current directory.

It's not that `./` triggers a special behaviour, it's just that if the command name doesn't contain any `/`, it does a `$PATH` lookup. `./cmd` is the most obvious way to give a path to `cmd` that contains a `/`.

The `./` prefix is also commonly used to  make sure a file name doesn't start with a problematic character for some commands.

For instance:

```
rm ./-f
```

removes `-f`, while `rm -f` would call `rm` with the `-f` option (`rm -- -f` would also work). Or:

```
cat ./-
awk '{print $1}' ./a==b.txt
```

where `--` wouldn't help.

You find that as `rm ./*` or `awk ... ./*` in scripts where you don't know if the expansion of `*` would yield problematic characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stéphane Chazelas! I do wonder if there is anything related the $PATH when asking this question!

Comment: If so, can I assume that I should use "./file" in most cases to prevent misuse, misinterpretation, and security vulnerability, unless I have compelling reason to use "file"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Several.

## C library functions

As mentioned in another answer, the `exec*p()` family of library functions use whether the name contains a slash character as a test for whether path searching should be performed.

### Further reading

- [What is "All shells and programs that use exec*p library calls handle searching"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290811/)

## Other things that search paths

Programs can of course do their own path searches outwith the C library.  They might be searching for things other than to execute them.  Or they might want slightly different behaviour to that of the C library functions, which has some little-known surprises to those not aware of what the POSIX standard mandates.  So they implement their own searching code.  Usually they will follow the conventions of the C library, and if the name contains a slash character they will just use the name as-is.

### For example:

Shells that have `CDPATH` or `cdpath` mechanisms perform this sort of search, and have this behaviour.  Here is the TENEX C shell:

```
~> set cdpath=(/usr /)
~> cd ./etc
./etc: No such file or directory.
~> cd etc
/etc
/etc>
```

## Filenames that begin with a minus sign

One of the ways of making sure that a filename that begins with a minus sign is not taken to be a command-line option is to prefix it with `./`.  For examples:

- `rm ./-rf` is a filename, and `rm -rf` is a command-line option.
- `find ./-name wibble` is scanning two directory trees and finding everything; whereas `find -name wibble` is scanning one directory tree and applying a pattern match.

### Further reading

- [How do I delete a file whose name begins with "-" (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/)

## Commands where the command syntax makes this important

Sometimes the syntax of the command is defined such that something is only a filename at all if it begins with a full stop.  Otherwise it is something else.  In a way, this is a generalization of the minus sign as an option character convention.

### For example:

With Dan Bernstein's [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) from daemontools, Bruce Guenter's [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html) from daemontools-encore, the djbwares [`multilog`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/guide/multilog.html), and Laurent Bercot's [`s6-log`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html) from s6, the command-line arguments are a *logging script* where the first letter of each argument indicates what kind of script command it is.  To denote a log directory, one has to give a command string argument that starts with a slash or a full stop character.  `multilog ./t ./u` means log to two directories; whereas `multilog t ./u` means log to one directory and prepend timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

`file` will search in your `PATH` for the file.

`./file` will ignore the `PATH` and search in the current directory.